# Optional parameter in C++ without overloading

Tags: c++, optional-parameters, default-parameters

I'd like to have a function with an optional parameter but without overloading the function. The reason I don't want to overload is because the function body is quite long, and the version with the optional parameter just differs by a single line.

```cxx
void myFunction(MyClass my_optional_arg = MyClass())
{
  // lots of statements

  if (optional_argument_was_passed)
    doSomething(my_optional_arg);

  // lots more statements
}

int main()
{
  myFunction();

  MyClass my_optional_object();
  myFunction(my_optional_object);
}
```

The problem that I have with the default parameter route is that I don't know how to check whether the optional parameter was passed or not, i.e., I don't know how to set the boolean flag `optional_argument_was_passed`. For example, just testing equality of the parameter with the default isn't sufficient because that same default value could be passed into the function. What I'd really like is something like this:

```cxx
void myFunction(MyClass my_optional_arg = some_unique_null_value)
{
  // lots of statements

  if (my_optional_arg != some_unique_null_value)
    doSomething(my_optional_arg);

  // lots more statements
}
```

It has been suggested that I do something like this:

```cxx
void myFunction()
{
  MyClass my_object();
  myFunction(my_object);
}
```

However, this is not quite what I need; the `myFunction(MyClass)` function is not necessarily the ultimate function to be used. If I call the function without the optional argument, `myFunction()`, then I don't want any object of class `MyClass` to even enter the function at all; rather, the statement that uses this object, called `doSomething(MyClass)` above, should be omitted.

It has also been suggested that I remove the common parts of both functions to its own function `myFunction()` and then create an overloaded wrapper function to call the statements with the optional parameter:

```cxx
void myFunction(MyClass my_optional_arg)
{
  doSomething(my_optional_arg);

  myFunction();
}
```

This is a solution, but it would be a bit messy because I have a lot of statements before AND after the `doSomething(MyClass)` call, so I'd need to split the function into several parts:

```cxx
void myFunction(MyClass my_optional_arg)
{
  myFunctionPartA();

  doSomething(my_optional_arg);

  myFunctionPartB();
}

void myFunctionPartA()
{
  // lots of statements
}

void myFunctionPartB()
{
  // lots more statements
}
```

Comment: Use `std::optional` for optional types? :) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional

Comment: Try and check if it is the *unusable* (preferably) answer. If it is, you're using the default. Then nothing was passed. Also, @pm100 's answer is sublime.

Comment: Blaz, thanks for the suggestion, I'm not familiar with `std::optional`. Would you mind giving the full example for this approach? I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply it.

Answer (score 2):

if the functions are similar then call one from the other. OR have an internal 'do all the work and take all the paramters' function that all the overloads call. This is a very common tactic

```
void Func() // func with foo defaulting to 42
{
    Func(42);
}

void Func(int foo)
{
  // one million lines of code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This doesn't quite address my issue - please see my edit.